# Why is the firebase_core Flutter package docked points for its pubspec homepage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, yaml, pubspec

## Background

I noticed the firebase_core 1.5.0 Scores page shows only 120/130 possible points. The package is docked 10 points for not following Dart file conventions. Under the section *Provide a valid pubspec.yaml*, the explanation is "Homepage URL isn't helpful." The homepage description for a pubspec file can be found here https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#homepage

[image: screenshot of the docked points for invalid pubspec.yaml]

## Question

What about their pubspec.yaml file —specifically the Homepage URL— is causing the points to be docked (deviating from the Dart file convention)? You can see from the file contents below that the line under "description" is indented, indicating that the problem may be there. However, this indentation seems purposeful from this commit https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/commit/a9e198d141324a15f76eeb19ae841b58dd3e3150.

The contents appear to be valid Yaml, so does the pubspec.yaml analyzer on pub.dev need to be adjusted to accommodate multi-line entries?

### pubspec.yaml contents

```
name: firebase_core
description: Flutter plugin for Firebase Core, enabling connecting to multiple
  Firebase apps.
homepage: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage
repository: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core
version: 1.5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Thanks for reporting this, as we'd actually overlooked that. There's a [PR](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/pull/5054) in flight to mark packages from firebase.google.com, so that they're no longer penalized.